# how to determine length of the array using its pointer?

Tags: c, arrays

Given pointer to an array as parameter to a function in C language, how to find its length?

```
int* mymap(int (*func)(int), int* Array) {
    int size = sizeof(Array); 
    // giving 8 (which is size of int*),but I want length of the array which I gave is 5.
    int* B = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
    printf("size %d\n", size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        B[i] = func(Array[i]);
    }
    return B;
}
```

Comment: You can't. Think about the length of the array as not being one of it's properties and store it somewhere while you need to use it. If you really need to pass just one parameter to any function handling this array, simply create a struct where you store the data with a pointer and the array size in another member.

Comment: Duplicate alarm!

Comment: This is finding length using pointer to an array, which is not possible as given in the answer below

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. `sizeof` works for array the way you expect it to be - returning the size of the array. Even if you passed array which will be converted to pointer to first element to it (Known as array decay) so basically you are not using `sizeof` over an array - rather over an decayed pointer to it. As a result now when you use it with `sizeof` operator it gives you sizeof pointer not size of array. Solution is to pass the length as argument to the function.

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3};
size_t size = sizeof array / sizeof array[0];

..
f(array, size);
```

Comment: ok,I am going for passing length as parameter.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi.: Yes now check.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi.: Like before I still mess up the spacing - is there any place where it is documented where I should use spaces...Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Nowhere, it's a matter of taste. You just need to make sense of it to yourself. For instance, a space after a coma makes a lot of sense and separates the *items* naturally, spaces around operators are very important because they let you see the operator immediately. Also, don't use too many, use just those that make the code as readable as possible.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi.: Well I see..it's at times confusing to guess about while answering. Get your point.

Comment: And apparently `sizeof` is an **operator** and *not* a function, so it does ***not require** parenthesis around it's argument*. Still if one needs the size of a type (not of a variable), the C language requires the type to be enclosed by parenthesis. So I'd prefer to write: `size_t s = sizeof s;` and `s = sizeof (size_t);` Note the spaces.

Comment: @alk.: Yes that I know but still gave...contradicted myself. Ah I see. You are mentioning in context of formatting..yes will try that. (You meant `sizeof (size_t)` )